# How can I add 2 articulations to a note as part of a post-event?

Tags: scheme, lilypond

I copied this example from [here](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/extending-big-page#inline-scheme-code), and it works fine, working as if I had simply entered `->`.

```
dashPlus = #(let ((m (make-music 'ArticulationEvent
                          'articulation-type "accent")))
       (set! (ly:music-property m 'tweaks)
             (acons 'font-size -3
                    (ly:music-property m 'tweaks)))
       m)
```

**However, I'm trying to figure out how to define a combination tenuto/marcato articulation**, which somehow got changed somewhere during the Finale file -> MusicXML -> .ly process from what I entered into Finale (the combination articulation) to an individual marcato articulation and an individual tenuto articulation attached to the same note (`-- ->`).

**How can I change this to add not only one accent, but a combination of both, and also somehow manipulate the articulations' `script-priority` values so that the tenuto is always stacked closest to the staff?** (I'm afraid my grasp of Scheme isn't too strong. I understand a few things but this is all way over my head.)